Confusion about EM waves in a conductor, AC in wires, and skin effect
I am trying to get my head around these different points:
From Maxwell's equations we find that an electromagnetic wave in a conductor decays in amplitude with a characteristic length of about 1 cm in a good conductor at 50 Hz.
Therefore how come AC can propagate over long distances (compared to 1 cm)?
It seems like this attenuation length does not directly relate to how far an EM wave can travel in a conductor. Why?
This attenuation length is invoked in the skin effect, which relates to how deep current penetrates in the radial direction (in a wire's cylindrical geometry) but what about propagation in the longitudinal direction? The same attenuation should be found there, shouldn't it?
Another related point is, if we imagine a large metal cube plugged to a wire at one point where sinusoidal potential is applied, would the resulting wave propagate through the volume of the cube, or only at its surface? And in any case with which attenuation constant?

The important fields are not inside the wire. They're in the space around the wire, usually either between the wire and ground or between one wire and another wire in a transmission line.
Since the field is found in the air rather than in the wire, the attenuation length depends on the characteristics of air rather than the characteristics of copper or aluminum. And in air the attenuation length for 50 or 60 Hz signals is so long that it doesn't (AFAIK) significantly affect the losses in power transmission.

if we imagine a large metal cube plugged to a wire at one point where sinusoidal potential is applied, would the resulting wave propagate through the volume of the cube, or only at its surface?

It depends on the frequency of the sinusoid and the skin depth in the material the cube is made of at that frequency, as compared to the dimensions of the cube. If the skin depth is smaller than the dimensions of the cube, then the currents will be significantly concentrated on the surface of the cube. The fields will, as in the transmission line case, mainly be found in the air around the cube rather than in the body of the cube.

That's very interesting, thanks!
